# JQuery file upload: already added files

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

How to validate file, that it already added (client side)?

Example: I have a file:"`c:\img\test.jpg`". And I added it.
 Then I try again to add that file.
I need to see if that image has already been added, then in the console I could saw: "the image has already been added"

But, if I copied that image to other directory:"`c:\img\222\test.jpg`" and try again upload, then that file will  add as new file.

Comment: Use `ajax` to check if file is already present , in the directory...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code.

Comment: use server side code to validate and then use ajax to send the response back to client as @shantaram_t said